# How can I add Option Group for custom data field in CiviCRM

Tags: custom-fields

I'm trying to create an option group for a custom data field.  It needs to be a multi-select dropdown. How can I build in CiviCRM

Eg

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Accommodations">
    <option value="Bed & Breakfasts">Bed &amp; Breakfasts</option>
    <option value="Camping">Camping</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Arts & Crafts">
    <option value="Artisans">Artisans</option>
    <option value="Artists">Artists</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: agree with Aidan - can you clarify why just adding these via Custom Field isn't an option. mostly folk would 'add custom field' and within that choose eg 'select' and then create their options

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add these in an extension?  If so, see [adding custom fields with civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#add-custom-fields) which suggests creating them via the GUI then exporting them.